# How to save rows of multiple buttons value to localstorage in angularjs and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

Here i have ng-repeat which populate number of rows with the value from controller.And each row contain three buttons labeled as excellent , good and bad.What i want to make is save one value to localstorage with cval and button value from three buttons at each row. And  selecting one should keep activate the button.

```
<div class="element" ng-repeat="cval in userOrderedValues track by $index">
    <div class="values">
        <p>{{cval}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
        <button class="button button-balanced" ng-model="selected" ng-click="saveStatus($index,cval,'good')" ng-class="{'active':val=='good' && current==$index}">excellent</button>
        <button class="button button-amber" ng-model="selected" ng-click="saveStatus($index,cval,'ok')" ng-class="{'active':val=='ok' && current==$index}">good</button>
        <button class="button button-assertive" ng-model="selected" ng-click="saveStatus($index,cval,'nw')" ng-class="{'active':val=='nw' && current==$index}">bad</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i can save these values to localstorage?  this is [codepen](http://codepen.io/surajkhanal/pen/YGoeLy?editors=1011) i have made for this

Comment: @Randall Flagg . sir could you help me to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has a module [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies/) that does just this. To use it you'll first need to add the script to pull in the module, then you'll need update your main module's dependencies to include $ngCookies and finally in your controller you can inject $cookies.

One approach is to maintain an object that contains any selections. You can use `$cookies.put()` and `$cookies.get()` to interact with simple values such as strings and numbers but since we'll be dealing with objects we'll want to use `$cookies.putObject()` and `$cookies.getObject()`.

Here's a plunkr with a simple example of how that might [look](https://plnkr.co/edit/SPw4qtK9eaRK5hP4km0c?p=preview). I tried doing it in your codepen fiddle but apparently codepen clears the cookies when the code changes.

Comment: Thank you very much  @Crhistian Ramirez .